# Examples of WPF forms for usual CRUD scenarios

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, crud

There are plenty of such  examples shown for Silverlight at recent Microsoft conferences ( Creating amazing LOB applications in SL 2,3,4  ... ) . 
They even invented DataForms starting from Silverlight varsion 3.
Basically I need an example of grid view ( maybe with possibility to filter, preferably DataGrid control  ) from which we may update/delete selected record(s) or add new ones working against SQL Server database without service layer.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be the problem here:

> working against SQL Server database without service layer.

Really, you should have a 3 (or N) tiered system, to protect your database.  Most good examples will take this into account, so things like RIA Services are really designed around this architecture.

That being said, you can bind a DataGrid to any `IList<Entity>`, so just use an ORM of your choice, and bind the data grid to a query.  Most ORMs will automatically handle the CRUD operations for you...